# Is there a way to test for snowballs that have broken?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know you can test for arrows in the ground using:

```
/testfor @e[type=Arrow] {inGround:1b}
```

But is there a way to test for snowballs that have broken (hit something)?

Comment: "Hit something" as in...? What else other than players or blocks?

Comment: I meant as in players and blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowball is removed when it hit something(broken), so you can't detect that.

However, you can use a marker entity to mark the location of the snowball, when there are no snowball around the marker entity, that means the snowball is probably broken.

The method i use is this: https://www.reddit.com/r/MinecraftCommands/comments/5tvs8l/teleporting_entities_to_each_player_every_tick/ (see my comment). This works for entities that won't teleport instantly. But you have to work on it a bit to adjust the accuracy(the range of snowball...)

Comment: Please always include the essential parts of an answer in the answer itself, not on an external website. Reddit is pretty reliable, so I'm not too worried about the post getting deleted or the site going down, but having an entire discussion thread elsewhere for an answer defeats the entire purpose of StackExchange's Q&A system.

Answer (score -3):

You can only test if an entity is near it like this:

```
/execute @e[type=snowball] ~ ~ ~ testfor @e[r=2]
```